# Kaa event subsystem not working

Tags: events, event-handling, iot, kaa

I am experimenting with Kaa event subsystem for one of my IoT application. I created a event class family and added the same to one of the projects keeping the property as "Both" as I want to send/receive both. My event triggering code looks something like:

```
    DesktopKaaPlatformContext desktopKaaPlatformContext = new DesktopKaaPlatformContext();
    kaaClient = Kaa.newClient(desktopKaaPlatformContext, new SimpleKaaClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStarted() {
            System.out.println("--= Kaa client started =--");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            System.out.println("--= Kaa client stopped =--");
        }
    }, true);

    // Obtain the event family factory.
    final EventFamilyFactory eventFamilyFactory = kaaClient.getEventFamilyFactory();

    Random rnRandom = new Random();
    event1 = eventFamilyFactory.getEventClassFamilyDemo();

    DemoEventsCTL event = new DemoEventsCTL(rnRandom.nextBoolean());
    kaaClient.start();
    event.setMachineOn(rnRandom.nextBoolean());
    event1.sendEventToAll(event);
    System.out.println("Hello : Event : " + event.getMachineOn() + "has been addded");

    }

}
```

And My Event handler looks like : 
    DesktopKaaPlatformContext desktopKaaPlatformContext = new DesktopKaaPlatformContext();

```
    kaaClient = Kaa.newClient(desktopKaaPlatformContext, new SimpleKaaClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStarted() {
            LOG.info("--= Kaa client started =--");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            LOG.info("--= Kaa client stopped =--");
        }
    }, true);
    final EventFamilyFactory eventFamilyFactory = kaaClient.getEventFamilyFactory();
    event1 = eventFamilyFactory.getEventClassFamilyDemo();
    event1.addListener(new EventClassFamilyDemo.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(DemoEventsCTL event, String source) {
              System.out.println(kaaClient.isAttachedToUser());
            System.out.println("The event received is :" + event.getMachineOn());

    });
    // Start the Kaa client and connect it to the Kaa server.
    kaaClient.start();
}
```

When I execute these applications separately, both run without any error logs, I see the connection to server successful. However, I do not see the sent events being received.
Will proxies be creating any issues? If anyone has tried before, can you tell me if I am missing anything?

Comment: To enable sending/receiving events to/from endpoints, at first the client should attach the endpoint to the user. `kaaClient.attachUser("userExternalId", "userAccessToken", userAttachCallback )`

Comment: Thanks Pete. I have attached user. and in logs, I can see the listener request logs as : 11:56:22.008 [pool-6-thread-1] DEBUG o.k.k.c.event.DefaultEventManager - Received event listener resolution response: [{"requestId": -2073544503, "listeners": [], "result": "SUCCESS"}] However, the listener onEvent method is not invoked still. Can you share a sample snippet so that I can check?

Comment: Please see below answer to see the two clients I tried with.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two Kaa client implementations that I used. One emits events and the other consumes those events.
You can see that both the clients are attached to the same user `("testverifier", "82884822542100000000")`.
First I ran the  `EventConsumer` so that it will be ready to catch events sent by `EventEmitter` when I start it.

**EventConsumer**

```
public class TestEventConsumer {

    private static KaaClient kaaClient;

    private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SampleEventListener.class.getSimpleName() + " Event Consumer Starting!");

        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        // Create the Kaa desktop context for the application.
        final DesktopKaaPlatformContext desktopKaaPlatformContext = new DesktopKaaPlatformContext();
        kaaClient = Kaa.newClient(desktopKaaPlatformContext, new FirstKaaClientStateListener(), true);

        kaaClient.start();

        consumeEvents();

        System.out.println("--= Press any key to exit =--");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException has occurred: {}" + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Stopping Event Consumer...");
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        kaaClient.stop();
    }

    private static class FirstKaaClientStateListener extends SimpleKaaClientStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onStarted() {
            super.onStarted();
            System.out.println("Kaa client (Event Consumer) started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            super.onStopped();
            System.out.println("Kaa client (Event Consumer) stopped");
        }
    }

    public static void consumeEvents() {
        kaaClient.attachUser("testverifier", "82884822542100000000", new UserAttachCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAttachResult(final UserAttachResponse response) {
                System.out.println("Attach response" + response.getResult());
            }
        });


        final EventFamilyFactory eventFamilyFactory = kaaClient.getEventFamilyFactory();
        final MyCustomECF myEcf = eventFamilyFactory.getMyCustomECF();

        myEcf.addListener(new MyCustomECF.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final MyCustomEvent event, final String source) {

                System.out.println("MyCustomEvent received from source : " + source + "Event Data Name : " + event.getName());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EventEmitter**

```
public class TestEventEmitter {

    private static KaaClient kaaClient;

    private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        // Create the Kaa desktop context for the application.
        final DesktopKaaPlatformContext desktopKaaPlatformContext = new DesktopKaaPlatformContext();

        kaaClient = Kaa.newClient(desktopKaaPlatformContext, new FirstKaaClientStateListener(), true);

        kaaClient.start();
        attachUserandEmitEvents();

        System.out.println("--= Press any key to exit =--");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException has occurred: {}" + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Stopping Event Emitter...");
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        kaaClient.stop();
    }

    private static void attachUserandEmitEvents() {
        // attach user
        kaaClient.attachUser("testverifier", "82884822542100000000", new UserAttachCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAttachResult(final UserAttachResponse response) {
                final EventFamilyFactory eventFamilyFactory = kaaClient.getEventFamilyFactory();

                final MyCustomECF myEcf = eventFamilyFactory.getMyCustomECF();

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    MyCustomEvent event = new MyCustomEvent();
                    event.setCustId("ID00" + i);
                    event.setName("Name - " + i);

                    myEcf.sendEventToAll(event);
                }               
            }
        });
    }

    private static class FirstKaaClientStateListener extends SimpleKaaClientStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onStarted() {
            super.onStarted();
            System.out.println("Kaa client (Event Emitter) started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            super.onStopped();
            System.out.println("Kaa client (Event Emitter) stopped");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippets. I tried with same. Both the clients are attached to same user but I am still facing issues with getting the event triggered in listener in another client. Any thoughts why so?

Comment: I still don't receive messages to the listeners. Are there any settings you have done? Like proxy etc.

Comment: Nope. No additional settings were made to send/receive the events. The only scenario where I failed to receive the events was when there was a mismatch between the user verifiers. Have you selected the user verifier when you create the SDK profile?

Comment: Yes. I have selected the same user verifier while creating SDK